# How to show other model column in Razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Currently i'm able to show all column in razer view from userRole model. 
Just curious if i like to show the SiteName column in UserRole Razor view, instead of showing SiteID, is it possible? I know it can be done via custom view model, but is it a must? Please correct me if i'm wrong!

UserRole Model:

```
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    *No SiteName column here....so i only can show SiteID in razor..
```

Site Model :

```
public int SiteID { get; set; }
public string SiteName { get; set; } <<-- the column i want..
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()

    {
         //need join table here perhaps?

         return View(db.User_Role.ToList());
    }
```

Razor View:

```
@model IEnumerable<FAB_Portal_POC.Models.UserRole>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Role)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SiteID)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SiteID) <<-- i want site name.
        </td>      
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Why do all MVC tutorials suck so hard? Repeat after me: don't use entity models as viewmodels. Period. Anyway, your `User_Role` entity model should have a `Site` navigation property which you can `Include()` to join the site table, then you can select the site name.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Personally, I don't think that's *always* true. The ViewModel can be anything that suffices the view' needs. Usually, the entity won't (or will cause too much trouble) but that's not always true.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok noted, i know it can be done by using custom view model. Just curious on it!

Comment: @haim no, not _always_, but it is _hardly ever sufficient_ to use entity models as view models in a real-life application. Sure, your My First TODO Website can work just fine, until you want to introduce related tables and present those in dropdowns, for example. Then the ViewBag hacks drip in, and you have a nightmare on your hands. Use viewmodels from the start. Edit: [QED](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35913352/266143).

Comment: @CodeCaster, I'm nitpicking here, but although entities are usually heavier and business-oriented (or at least should be), some (Entitiy Framwork) "entities" are merely value-objects and that leads to people literally duplicating an entire `Country` type (for example) just for the sake of "not using entities as view-models".

Comment: @haim there's no harm in that. In most cases you want a disconnected scenario anyway, as you either don't use all database fields in your view, or want more information in your view than is in the entity, with the additional benefit that your views don't suddenly break when you alter the database, while mapping code (especially using tools like AutoMapper) is easily testable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that your `UserRole` entity model doesn't seem to have a navigation property.

You don't *need* to, but then querying becomes awkward:

```
var rolesWithSite = from r in db.User_Role
                    join s in db.Sites on s.ID equals r.Site_ID
                    select new
                    {
                        Role = r,
                        Site = s
                    }
                    .ToList();
```

While when you add a navigation property (perhaps even instead of the foreign key property):

```
public class User_Role
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
}
```

Querying will become a whole lot easier:

```
var rolesWithSite = db.User_Role.Include(r => r.Site).ToList();
```

You can then introduce a viewmodel:

```
public class UserRoleViewModel
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Site { get; set; }
}
```

And map the query results to that:

```
var viewModels = rolesWithSite.Select(r => new UserRoleViewModel
{
    UserID = r.UserID,
    UserName = r.UserName,
    Role = r.Role,
    Site = r.Site.SiteName,

}).ToList();

return View(viewModels);
```

Answer (score 1):

Entities and Models are very different.

You have to create a specific model for your page.

something like this :

PageModel

```
public string UserName { get; set; }
public string SiteName { get; set; }
```

In your controller your have to prepare all the data you want to send to the page. It s here that you will "associate" your entities to your pagemodel

```
public ActionResult Index()

{
     var roles = db.User_Role.ToList();
     var sites = db.Sites.ToList(); // i don t know how you get this information in your exemple.

     //define here every property of the PageModel you want to use there
     var model = new PageModel();
     model.UserName = roles.UserName;
     model.SiteName = sites.Select(...).SiteName;

     return View(model);
}
```

then in razor view

```
@model IEnumerable<FAB_Portal_POC.Models.PageModel>
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can store the sites list in the ViewBag and show the site name by extracting it from the ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     ViewBag.Sites = db.Sites.ToList();
     return View(db.User_Role.ToList());
}
```

And the View:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ViewBag.Sites.Single(s => s.SiteID == item.SiteID).SiteName)
</td>
```

Another, and to me a better approach, would be to create a `ViewModel` for your view which contains all of the data that you need. And return that view model to your view.

```
public class UserSiteViewModel
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't suggest bad practices like that. You don't know how big `db.Sites` is, and you don't want to do business logic like that in your view. Just introduce a viewmodel.

Comment: Agreed @CodeCaster , never to have business logic in view, Use models in fact.

Comment: @CodeCaster Which is what I've said at the end of the post anyways.

Comment: Who is going to read that if your answer contains copy-pasteable code that seems to work?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to do that the simple one is you have to create new class name UserRoleViewData and mention these fields and pass the class object to view. just like that.

New Class **UserRoleViewData** Look like this

```
public int UserID { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
public int SiteID { get; set; }
public string SiteName { get; set; }
```

and your **Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()

{
      List<className> dto = (from a in _db.User_Role
                 join b in db.Site on a.SiteID equals b.SiteID 
                  select (new classname { UserID =a.UserID , UserName =a.UserName , SiteID =a.SiteID , SiteName =b.SiteName })).ToList();
     return View(dto);
}
```

In View You have to change `@model IEnumerable<FAB_Portal_POC.folderName.ClassName>`
and map other property on view like others.I hope u'll understand and this will help you.

Comment: is it need to create a DTO on the list there? Because it shows the "The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query". Anyway thanks for your info :)

Comment: You have multiple ways to do this but i share simple one.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `ViewBag` , join between 2 tables and store result in another `viewModel` it's vary bad idea. Please check out reference link, It will really help you to do Code in Very good direction. [Click Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)